# How to create Timeline per Node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I had tried to ask this question earlier and will try and restate the question. I have a graph of people or nodes representing people and each person has a calendar associated with him/her.
The calendar is represented using a Timeline. I came across this old thread (http://lists.neo4j.org/pipermail/user/2011-April/007966.html), which kind of says that implementing the model of Timeline-per-Node is difficult with LuceneTimeline and the older B-tree implementation was more efficient. Is it still true?

Is there a B-tree implementation available in version 1.8 and higher ?

Has anyone faced a similar problem ?

I am working on building a plugin to expose a REST interface for managing Timelines. The problems I'm facing are:

- How to retrieve an existing LuceneTimeline ?
- How to associate a Timeline with every Node ?
- Are there any examples anywhere ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/neo4j/graph-collections/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/collections/timeline/TestTimeline.java is probably what you should. This however does not work great over REST as it is using the Java Embedded API. Either send over Groovy code, or do a custom Neo4j Server plugin, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-plugins.html .

Also, you can do something like that with Cypher, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-cookbook-path-tree.html